# Error: png.h no such file or directory

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, libpng, native-activity

Hello im trying to load textures from PNG files.
Im using visual studio 2010 with VisualGDB plugin to run Android NDK.
I created project from native-activity sample and trying to add libpng as described in "Android NDK Begginer`s guide" book. I downloaded libpng 1.5.12 and paste it in $(android ndk)/sources. Then i creates Android.mk file with this content:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LS_C=$(subst $(1)/,,$(wildcard $(1)/*.c))
LOCAL_MODULE := png LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(filter-out example.c pngtest.c,$(call LS_C,$(LOCAL_PATH)))
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) 
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then im trying to include this static lib in my project Android.mk file like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

S_CPP=$(subst $(1)/,,$(wildcard $(1)/*.cpp))
LOCAL_MODULE    := native-activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lpng
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue png

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
$(call import-module,libpng)
```

But when im trying to include png.h as described in the book - i get the error

```
error : png.h: No such file or directory
```

P.S. Visual Studio - sees this file and offers autocomplete.